# function should take two arguments , an array and the size of the array

Tags: c, function, struct

I need help with the following please:

**define a function that returns the population of the smallest city 
(popolation wise) in an array of cities. the function should take two 
arguments: an array of cities and the length of the array.**

this is my code:

```
struct city
{

char name[20];
int pop;

};

 int func1(struct city cities[], int i) // these are the arguments

{

    for(i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        cities[i].pop;
    }

    cities[0].pop=2500;
    cities[1].pop=3000;

    return cities[0].pop;
}
```

I just want this to work, but it dosnt compile and dosnt give errors ether.

Comment: Your question is not clear even with your code. What's the for loop for?

Comment: It neither compiles *nor* gives errors? It's a problem with your compiler.

Comment: the first line overwrites i. i isnt behaving like an argument

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the compilation *process*, not this program.

Comment: there are no side effects to the body of that loop, so it can be optimized out

Comment: If it doesn't compile, the compiler will tell you WHY it isn't compiling. I advise you learn how to read compiler messages, as that will be very helpful if you plan on continuing C development.

Comment: Hello ! I just try to compile your code with a online compiler and it works fine. After I add the main function. Are you sure there is none error messages when you try to compile ?

Comment: Hi everybody!  about the for loop is for giving the array a size!!

Answer (score 1):

There are few errors in your code.
For instance, you can't find the array size by looping in the array. It only works for "string" because they have a end character '\0'.

The size of the array, as you mentionned is passed on the second argument of your function.

So what you want to do is, I suppose :

```
int func1(struct city cities[], size_t i) // these are the arguments
{
    if (i == 0)
        return 0;
    int min = cities[0].pop;
    for(size_t j=1; j < i; ++j)
    {
        min = cities[i].pop < min ? cities[i].pop : min;
    }
    return min;
}
```

Regards.

Comment: If my answer is what you expected you can validate it otherwise tell us more precisely what you want. Regards

Comment: Note: Better to use `size_t i`,`j` and return value rather than `int i`.

Comment: I made the changes in my function. At first, I use int to correspond with the signature of the function he gave but you are right size_t are a better choice.

Comment: Note: Oops on my suggest concerning making the return value `size_t` as  the function is to "returns the population of the smallest city".  OTOH, instead returning the index (with type `size_t`) is useful so the population _and the name_ of the smallest city can be readily determined.